# Comparing elements of an array to a scalar and getting the max in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compare the elements of an array to a scalar and get an array with the maximum of the compared values. That's I want to call

```
import numpy as np
np.max([1,2,3,4], 3)
```

and want to get

```
array([3,3,3,4])
```

But I get

```
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

When I run

```
np.max([[1,2,3,4], 3])
```

I get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which is one of the two elements in the list that is not the result I seek for. Is there a Numpy solution for that which is fast as the other built-in functions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is already built into numpy with the function [`np.maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```py
a = np.arange(1,5)
n = 3

np.maximum(a, n)
#array([3, 3, 3, 4])
```

This doesn't mutate `a`:

```py
a
#array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If you want to mutate the original array as in @jamylak's answer, you can give `a` as the output:

```py
np.maximum(a, n, a)
#array([3, 3, 3, 4])

a
#array([3, 3, 3, 4])
```

[Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

> `maximum(x1, x2[, out])`
>
> Element-wise maximum of array elements.
>      Equivalent to `np.where(x1 > x2, x1, x2)` but faster and does proper broadcasting.

Comment: Important note that can make you save 10 minutes : `np.maximum`  is another function than `np.max` (which also exists!). It won't work with `max`, you have to use `maximum` :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> n = 3
>>> a[a<n] = n
>>> a
array([3, 3, 3, 4])
```