# select max when comparing single element & array in python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

How to select max when comparing single element & array in python?

ex:
i = 5 & a = np.array([3,9,1,4,6])

expected result is an array = [5,9,5,5,6]

by comparing i to each element of a & select the max.

Besides use for loop, is there a vectorization faster way?

Comment: [maximum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) returns the max value of an elemet-wise comparison: `np.maximum(a,i)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing elements of an array to a scalar and getting the max in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587427/comparing-elements-of-an-array-to-a-scalar-and-getting-the-max-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `numpy.maximum`:

```
import numpy as np

i = 5
a = np.array([3,9,1,4,6])

print(np.maximum(i,a))
# [5,9,5,5,6]
```